# How to link to the current anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a dynamic table which is filled with JSON data. I want to make some cells of this table clickable, but when I'm clicking on the cell and trying to alert it, I'm alerting the whole column. How can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
    function onLoad(){
        var url='example.js';
        $.getJSON(url, function(json){
            var table = $("#table" );


            var c=0;
            for( var i=0; i<json.length;i++){
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                var td = $('<td>');
                td.html(json[i].name);
                tr.append(td);
                td = $('<td> ');
                td.html(json[i].category);
                tr.append(td);
                td = $('<td>');
                td.html(json[i].amount);
                tr.append(td);
                td = $('<td>');

                td.html('<a>               '+json[i].location);

                tr.append(td);
                td = $('<td>');
                td.html(json[i].date);
                tr.append(td);

                table.append(tr);
                $("a").attr("href","#");
            }

            $('body').append(table);
        });
    }

$("#table").on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).children().children().children().children().text())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$("#table").on('click', 'td', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text())
});
```